# Github merge upstream changes to existing PR

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I have a pull request in which I need to do some fixes. In the meanwhile the master is by many commits ahead and I need to update my PR with them before I commit the fix.
If I do a rebase first from my locally checked master and then do a forced push of my PR branch, will the PR also contain the changes from the merge?

I just want to have an updated PR which only contains my changes as in a similar situaltion previously I was asked to "somehow" clean up my PR. How is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it will also contain the merge. You can try to cherry-pick your commits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I do a rebase first from my locally checked master and then do a forced push of my PR branch, will the PR also contain the changes from the merge?

If you rebase onto your "locally checked master" and push, the PR will only be up to date with your local version of master.

You can checkout master and pull changed from your origin, then rebase onto that, or rebase onto `origin/master` after a `git fetch`, and you will then have a branch only containing new commits (new changes included in the branch history).

> I just want to have an updated PR which only contains my changes as in a similar situaltion previously I was asked to "somehow" clean up my PR. How is that possible?

You have two options - [`rebase`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) and [`merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) - you should look at the documentation for each of them, but here's a quick comparison of each:

- **Rebase:** will rewind your branch, reset it to whatever you rebase onto, then re-apply your changes again. This means that when your branch is not up-to-date, rebasing will apply the new changes from origin *before* your changes. You resolve any merge conflicts at the start of the rebase (back in history potentially in *your* commits), and whenever required as the history is re-played.

  - *Pros:* clean commit history
  - *Cons:* you will have to force push, many people don't like doing this. Commit hashes will change when you rebase.
- **Merge:** will apply the new changes from origin *on top* of your changes. This means that your change will exist in the history, then the new changes will be ahead of it. You only resolve conflicts once, at the *end* of your commit history (generally easier).

  - *Cons:* That, and commit hashes don't change.
  - *Pros:* No force push required.

Generally speaking if someone on GitHub asks you to update your branch then they're probably suggesting that you rebase, that way it is kept cleaner in terms of the commit history.

Squashing your commits together is also a common request from repository owners on GitHub. This is only possible with rebasing, however [GitHub now offers the ability to squash commits when merging pull requests](https://github.com/blog/2141-squash-your-commits), so many repository owners will not bother asking you to squash as they can do it themselves now.

[Here's a good comparison](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/) of each method by Atlassian.

Answer (score 1):

If you rebase your work on top of current upstream master and then do a force-push, the new PR branch replaces the old one. So the old commits vanish from the PR and the new commits are there, ready to be merged.

Comment: Thanks. So that the update from the master will be there too? Should I close current PR and create a new branch/PR?

Comment: Why? Just force-push and everything will be good. If you created a PR from your `foo` against `master` and `master` evolved, so you rebase your `foo` against new `master`, fix the conflicts and force push and again the PR just contains only your changes.