# Update PR with the base branch

Tags: git, github, rebase

How to use squash the commits before merging into main.

Comment: `git fetch origin main` -> `git rebase origin/main` -> `git add` -> `git rebase --continuegit rebase --continue` -> `git push -f origin [your-branch-name]`

Comment: You've added the tag `rebase`, so I guess you already know you want to rebase. Did you try, was there a specific issue?

Comment: I am confused in the exact steps to follow. To do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github merge upstream changes to existing PR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36992654/github-merge-upstream-changes-to-existing-pr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

1. `git checkout main` - 1/2: let's get the latest version of `main`
2. `git pull` - 2/2: let's get the latest version of `main`
3. `git checkout feature_branch` - 1/2: let's get the latest commits in `main` into the feature branch
4. `git merge main` or `git rebase main` - 2/2: let's get the latest commits in `main` into the feature branch
5. `git push` - push the changes in the feature branch to GitHub. The PR will be updated automatically.